# How to construct the logic in this SQL WHERE clause?

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server, stored-procedures

I am trying to write a stored procedure to search through text fields of a table as follows:

**TABLE: [User]**

```
[Id] BIGINT PRIMARY KEY, IDENTITY (1, 1)
[Name] NVARCHAR(100) NOT NULL
[Email] NVARCHAR(100) NOT NULL, UNIQUE
```

The production database has many columns and a very large data set. The point of this SP is to speed up searching as much as practically possible.

What I tried:

1. EntityFrameworkCore LINQ queries.
2. Generating SQL on-the-fly using ADO .NET.
3. The stored procedure below.

The SP has yeilded the best results so far but the results are not accurate.

**TEST SCRIPT**

```
USE [TestDatabase]

--DELETE FROM [User] -- Commented for your safety.
DBCC CHECKIDENT ('[User]', RESEED, 0)
INSERT INTO [User] ([Name], [Email]) VALUES ('Name 01', 'Email01@Email.com')
INSERT INTO [User] ([Name], [Email]) VALUES ('Name 02', 'Email02@Email.com')
INSERT INTO [User] ([Name], [Email]) VALUES ('Name 03', 'Email03@Email.com')

EXECUTE SpUserSearch 0
EXECUTE SpUserSearch 1
EXECUTE SpUserSearch 0, NULL, NULL
EXECUTE SpUserSearch 1, NULL, NULL
EXECUTE SpUserSearch 0, 'Name 01', '@'
EXECUTE SpUserSearch 1, 'Name 01', '@'
```

**RESULTS:**

[image: TEST SCRIPT RESULTS]

The first 4 queries should have returned ALL rows.

- Query 1: Expected Rows: 3, Returned Rows: 0.
- Query 2: Expected Rows: 3, Returned Rows: 0.
- Query 3: Expected Rows: 3, Returned Rows: 0.
- Query 4: Expected Rows: 3, Returned Rows: 0.
- Query 5: Expected Rows: 1, Returned Rows: 3.
- Query 6: Expected Rows: 3, Returned Rows: 3.

**STORED PROCEDURE:**

```
CREATE OR ALTER PROCEDURE SpUserSearch
    @Condition BIT = 0, -- AND=0, OR=1.
    @Name NVARCHAR(100) = NULL,
    @Email NVARCHAR(100) = NULL
AS
BEGIN

    SET NOCOUNT ON;

    DECLARE @UseName BIT
    DECLARE @UseEmail BIT

    IF ((@Name IS NULL) OR (LEN(@Name) = 0)) SET @UseName = 0 ELSE SET @UseName = 1
    IF ((@Email IS NULL) OR (LEN(@Email) = 0)) SET @UseEmail = 0 ELSE SET @UseEmail = 1

    IF (@Condition = 0)
        SELECT [Id], [Name], [Email]
        FROM [User]
        WHERE
            ((@UseName = 1) OR ([Name] LIKE '%' + @Name + '%'))
            AND
            ((@UseEmail = 1) OR ([Email] LIKE '%' + @Email + '%'))
    ELSE
        SELECT [Id], [Name], [Email]
        FROM [User]
        WHERE
            ((@UseName = 1) OR ([Name] LIKE '%' + @Name + '%'))
            OR
            ((@UseEmail = 1) OR ([Email] LIKE '%' + @Email + '%'))

    RETURN (@@ROWCOUNT)

END
```

There are two questions here:

1. What am I doing wrong in the SP logic?
2. Is this the most performant way to condition on the `WHERE` clause? I am not sure if `CURSOR`s apply in this context.

Any advice would be appreciated.

Comment: No query is going to be performant with those leading wildcards. A *full* table/index scan will be needed.

Comment: If you want high performance free text search on SQL Server have a look into [Full-Text Search](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/search/full-text-search?view=sql-server-ver15)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your logic is wrong: you need `@UseName = 0` and `@UseEmail = 0` in the `AND` half of the procedure. You also need to swap `(@UseName = 1) OR` to `(@UseName = 1) AND` in the `OR` half.

Although it's hard to say what the intention would be for `@Condition` if only one search value is supplied: what if `[Name]` or `[Email]` in the row is null?

```sql
CREATE OR ALTER PROCEDURE SpUserSearch
    @Condition BIT = 0, -- AND=0, OR=1.
    @Name NVARCHAR(100) = NULL,
    @Email NVARCHAR(100) = NULL
AS
BEGIN

    SET NOCOUNT ON;

    DECLARE @UseName BIT
    DECLARE @UseEmail BIT

    IF ((@Name IS NULL) OR (LEN(@Name) = 0)) SET @UseName = 0 ELSE SET @UseName = 1
    IF ((@Email IS NULL) OR (LEN(@Email) = 0)) SET @UseEmail = 0 ELSE SET @UseEmail = 1

    IF (@Condition = 0)
        SELECT [Id], [Name], [Email]
        FROM [User]
        WHERE
            ((@UseName = 0) OR ([Name] LIKE '%' + @Name + '%'))
            AND
            ((@UseEmail = 0) OR ([Email] LIKE '%' + @Email + '%'))
    ELSE
        SELECT [Id], [Name], [Email]
        FROM [User]
        WHERE
            ((@UseName = 1) AND ([Name] LIKE '%' + @Name + '%'))
            OR
            ((@UseEmail = 1) AND ([Email] LIKE '%' + @Email + '%'))

    RETURN (@@ROWCOUNT)

END
```

Performance-wise: this is never going to be great, [because of the leading wildcard](https://use-the-index-luke.com/sql/where-clause/searching-for-ranges/like-performance-tuning).

You may also get parameter-sniffing problems, for which the solution is usually to build the query dynamically, as I show in [an answer to your other question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/70148591/14868997).

Comment: That seems to have done the trick. Also, both fields are non-nullable. I edited the question to clarify. By the way, good link for wildcards. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

**Question 1**

I think the problem is around the `OR` predicates inside the parenthesis in each condition, I believe it should be an `AND` predicate like shown below:

```
CREATE OR ALTER PROCEDURE SpUserSearch
    @Condition BIT = 0, -- AND=0, OR=1.
    @Name NVARCHAR(100) = NULL,
    @Email NVARCHAR(100) = NULL
AS
BEGIN

    SET NOCOUNT ON;

    DECLARE @UseName BIT
    DECLARE @UseEmail BIT

    IF ((@Name IS NULL) OR (LEN(@Name) = 0)) SET @UseName = 0 ELSE SET @UseName = 1
    IF ((@Email IS NULL) OR (LEN(@Email) = 0)) SET @UseEmail = 0 ELSE SET @UseEmail = 1

    IF (@Condition = 0)
        SELECT [Id], [Name], [Email]
        FROM [User]
        WHERE
            ((@UseName = 1) AND ([Name] LIKE '%' + @Name + '%'))
            AND
            ((@UseEmail = 1) AND ([Email] LIKE '%' + @Email + '%'))
    ELSE
        SELECT [Id], [Name], [Email]
        FROM [User]
        WHERE
            ((@UseName = 1) AND ([Name] LIKE '%' + @Name + '%'))
            OR
            ((@UseEmail = 1) AND ([Email] LIKE '%' + @Email + '%'))

    RETURN (@@ROWCOUNT)

END
```

**Question 2**

I agree with Larnu's comment that, because you're using those wildcards, you probably can't work much on performance.

Answer (score 1):

`@UseName` and `@UseEmail` are not necessary. you can simply null the variable if it's a whitespace, and then make use of `ISNULL` under the `WHERE` along with the `@Condition` as well. (no need for the `IF/ELSE`

Here is the procedure wearing a swimming goggles :) :

```
CREATE OR ALTER PROCEDURE SpUserSearch
    @Condition BIT = 0, -- AND=0, OR=1.
    @Name NVARCHAR(100) = NULL,
    @Email NVARCHAR(100) = NULL
AS
BEGIN

    SET NOCOUNT ON;
   -- this would covers NULL and Whitespace
    SET @Name = CASE WHEN @Name IS NOT NULL AND LEN(@Name) = 0 THEN NULL ELSE '%' + @Name + '%' END

    SET @Email = CASE WHEN @Email IS NOT NULL AND LEN(@Email) = 0 THEN NULL ELSE '%' + @Email + '%' END
    
    SELECT [Id], [Name], [Email]
    FROM 
        [User]
    WHERE
    (
            @Condition = 0 
        AND 
        (
                [Name] LIKE ISNULL(@Name, [Name])
            AND [Email] LIKE ISNULL(@Email, [Email])
        )
    )
    OR 
    (
            @Condition = 1 
        AND 
        (
                [Name] LIKE ISNULL(@Name, [Name])
            OR  [Email] LIKE ISNULL(@Email, [Email])
        )
    )

    RETURN (@@ROWCOUNT)

END
```